# Oscillating essential discontinuities exist?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity) an discontinuity of $f$ is essential if and only if either the left or the right limit is infinite *or does not exist*.

> Is it possible to construct an undefined non-infinite functional limit? (If
>   so, could you show me such an example please)

I'm not sure it's correct but until now I thought of non-existing limits as ones that are $\pm \infty$. But maybe this was wrong and a limit of the kind $(-1)^n$ could be constructed for a function also.

A simple example does probably not work: I believe that if we define $f$ to be zero everywhere except $f({1 \over n}) = (-1)^n$ then the limit of $f$ at $0$ would probably be zero because $f$ is mostly zero around zero. Right?

Comment: In your example $f(1/n)=(-1)^n$, the limit doesn't exist. It follows directly from $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. If you want to see a *continuous* example, try $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and study $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard example is
$$
f(x)=\sin\frac1x,\quad x\ne0.
$$
As $x\to0$, $f(x)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$.